# Go language sentiment analysis

Tags: math, go, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I'm using the following library to perform some sentiment analysis of Facebook posts on my feed as an experiment for a bit of fun: https://github.com/cdipaolo/sentiment

But the problem I'm facing is that the Analysis object that is returned from the model.SentimentAnalysis() call doesn't have a weighted score. The score value it returns for the sentence is either 0 or 1. This makes it too vaguely defined, and I'd like to have a scale of sentiment for each Facebook post, so a float from 0.0-1.0 would be ideal where 1 is 100% positive and 0 is 100% negative.

Is there a way I can utilize the Words variable in the object (in this file you can see it down the bottom https://github.com/cdipaolo/sentiment/blob/master/model.go) to loop over each of the word scores in the sentence to create my own weighted sentiment score? For example, would something like positive_words / total_words work? That would give me a number representing what percentage of positive sentiment the post is, but then the weighting problem comes back into it again because the words aren't weighted either, so for example say I got back a score of 0.75, in reality the true score could be a lot less because the words may have only very slightly been above the positive threshold but I don't know that because it's only either a 0 for negative or a 1 for positive, it's not a weighted float value.

So my question here is, is there some way mathematically that I can create my own weight score given the data that is provided, or do I not have enough data to do this?

Comment: Looks like you need to adapt `Predict` https://github.com/cdipaolo/goml/blob/master/text/bayes.go to give you intermediate scores.